# Websocket not receiving messages from Django Channels server websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently working on a project using Django Channels for WebSocket communication. However, I'm facing an issue where the WebSocket connection is established successfully, but messages are not being received on the client side.

- WebSocket connection is established without errors.
- I've verified that the Django Channels server is sending messages.
- However, the client-side WebSocket does not seem to receive any messages.

my asgi.py is

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import transposys_main.routing
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'transposys_main.settings')
django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        URLRouter(
            transposys_main.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

my consumer.py is

```
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(\__name_\_)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class DepartmentCreatedConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):

logger.info(f"WebSocket connected: {self.channel_name}")

await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):

logger.info(f"WebSocket disconnected: {self.channel_name}")

async def receive(self, text_data):

logger.info(f"WebSocket message received: {text_data}")

try:

text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

message_type = text_data_json.get('type')

message = text_data_json.get('message')

if message_type == 'department.created':

logger.info(f"New Department: {message}")

except json.JSONDecodeError as e:

logger.error(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")

async def department_created(self, event):

try:

logger.info(f"Department created event received: {event\['message'\]}")

await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({

'type': 'department.created',

'message': event\['message'\],

}))

except Exception as e:

logger.error(f"Error sending WebSocket message: {e}")
```

routing is

```
from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import DepartmentCreatedConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = \[

re_path(r'ws/department_creation/$', DepartmentCreatedConsumer.as_asgi()),

\]
```

my wsgi serve waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 transposys_main.wsgi:application and asgi in daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 transposys_main.asgi:application i cant receive any message

in my html browser i got connected but when i sent notification that notification not seeing in html page or console

Comment: Please edit your post to put the code in a code block, so that formatting is rendered correctly here, just like it would be in your coding editor. I was going to fix it, but you removed all indentation, so you need to delete all the code here and cut and paste it again from your editor. As a proper code block, you'll see you won't have to fix anything: The line before your code and the line after your code should be just three backticks.